# Jquery puff effect not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add an effect to my page when it loads. But the effect `$( "#toggle" ).toggle( "puff" );` does not work. Things like `$( "#toggle" ).fadeIn( "puff" );` work. But I can't get the puff effect to work. It just uses the standard toggle animation. This puff effect is exactly what I need in my project. Why is it not working? 
This is what the file looks like. I saw this effect on https://api.jqueryui.com/puff-effect/ I'm quite new to this so sorry if this is a bad mistake

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#showEffect").hide();
  $("#showEffect").toggle("puff");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card" id="showEffect">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h3 class="card-title">Test</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you included JS and CSS for jQuery UI? From the above snippet I don't see one.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you want it to "puff" open, if so, you'll want to call the `.toggle()` function instead of `.hide()`, like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#showEffect").toggle();
    $("#showEffect").toggle( "puff" );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card" id="showEffect">
  <div class="card-body">
  <h3 class="card-title">Test</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's my guess as to why this is the case:

`.toggle()` probably sets a variable like `isOn`, whereas `.hide()` doesn't, so you call `.toggle()` the first time without any effect to hide immediately which sets `isOn` to `false`, and then call `.toggle()` again with the effect. On the second `.toggle()` `isOn` is `false` which means `.toggle()` will toggle it open with the effect, instead of closing it with the effect.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are missing:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

and

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

but don't make sense use toggle on load, as you are hiding the the time on load the effect will be always fade in. Toggle is useful to use in things like click events but not on load.